# Bash script logic to extract text stretched across multiple lines in a file based on delimiters

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

In my script, I need to store the contents of TEXT('...') from file **$CURFILEPATH** into a bash variable named **$SRCTEXT**.

The TEXT('...') variable is included in various files that contain IBM i CLLE commands.

In CLLE, the `+` is a continuation character, so ignore that at the end of the line.

The TEXT('...') target might also contain doubled single quotes, like this: `TEXT('Bob O''Malley''s favorite DTAARA').  It might also contain other characters like` (`,` )`,

Here is a straightforward example of a file where the **$SRCTEXT** to extract is on a single line:

```
/* Create and set data area for PHP binary location - 1.0.24 */
CRTDTAARA  DTAARA(PHPPATH) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(255) +
VALUE(' ') TEXT('Path to PHP Binaries')
```

For that file **$SRCTEXT** should be "Path to PHP Binaries".

And here is a more difficult example where the TEXT('...') variable stretches across multiple lines, via continuation character `+`.

```
/* Create and set data area for Python binary location - 1.05 */
CRTDTAARA  DTAARA(PYPATH) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(255) +
VALUE('/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin') TEXT('Path to +
Python Binaries')
```

For that file $SRCTEXT should be "Path to Python Binaries"

Additional edge case example file that uses `''`s and `()`s in the TEXT('...') target

```
/* Create and set data area for Python binary location - 1.05 */
CRTDTAARA  DTAARA(PYPATH) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(255) +
VALUE('/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin') TEXT('Path to +
Python Language''s Binaries (this is an edge case)')
```

For that file $SRCTEXT should be "Path to Python Language''s Binaries (this is an edge case)"

Note that the quotes should remain doubled.

Though unlikely, the TEXT('...') variable *could* stretch across 3 or more lines with continuation characters.  It would be nice to handle that, but a 2 line solution is acceptable.

Any Bash solution using awk, sed, grep, etc... is acceptable.

ChatGPT gave me something like `grep -oP "(?<=TEXT ')[^']+" $CURFILEPATH` but that wasn't working.

Comment: @Ed Morton The contents will be used later in an IBM i command that looks like this:  `system -v "CHGPFM FILE(${src_lib}/${src_file}) MBR($src_member) SRCTYPE(${src_type}) TEXT('${src_text}')"`  When I use this command while SSH'd to an IBM i (where the 'system' command is valid), if there is a single quote in the contents of $src_text, I get an error.  If I double it, it works fine.  So yes, keeping the quotes doubled is important here.

Comment: I don't know what an "IBM i" command is but if that line of code in your comment were something you were trying to execute on a Unix system using, say, `sh -c "...command..."` then you'd also be getting a syntax error from a single quote but doubling them in the variable would be the wrong solution as you'd end up with no quotes in the command so you may want to take another look at that.

Comment: Try setting this `src_text="Hello'World"` and then running `sh -c "echo '${src_text}'"` and it'll fail with `sh: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '`. If to try to solve that you double the quote with `src_text="Hello''World"` then you can run `sh -c "echo '${src_text}'"` and it'll no longer produce an error message but it also won't print any quote, it'll output `HelloWorld`. Ask a new question about it if you'd like help with how to solve that problem if it really is a problem in your code as I think it might be.

Comment: @Ed Morton _IBM i_ is not a command, its an operating system put out by IBM that runs on IBM POWER servers, OS400 architecture.  Its evolved from AS400 and iSeries.  IBM i has a PASE environment where BASH scripts and other languages like PYTHON, NodeJS, R, etc run.  It also has a traditional environment where CL, COBOL, and RPG programs run.  'system' is a specialized command that allows you to call traditional programs from the PASE environment.  If you are ever interested, PUB400.COM has free logins where you can log in via 5250 terminal or SSH over port 2222 and try things.

Comment: More information - the system command I mentioned in my first comment is specific to the OS400 architecture (IBM i operating system) and its completely valid to have the doubled single quotes, since they will be handled by CL command processing.  The command is documented by IBM here:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=utilities-pase-i-system-utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT` (and the `\<` word boundary):

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<TEXT[(]\047(([^\047]|\047\047)+)\047[)]' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/^[^\047]+\047|\047[^\047]+$/,""); gsub(/\+\n/,""); gsub(/\047\047/,"\047"); print}' file1
Path to PHP Binaries
```

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<TEXT[(]\047(([^\047]|\047\047)+)\047[)]' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/^[^\047]+\047|\047[^\047]+$/,""); gsub(/\+\n/,""); gsub(/\047\047/,"\047"); print}' file2
Path to Python Binaries
```

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<TEXT[(]\047(([^\047]|\047\047)+)\047[)]' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/^[^\047]+\047|\047[^\047]+$/,""); gsub(/\+\n/,""); gsub(/\047\047/,"\047"); print}' file3
This is JDubbTX's Text
```

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<TEXT[(]\047(([^\047]|\047\047)+)\047[)]' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/^[^\047]+\047|\047[^\047]+$/,""); gsub(/\+\n/,""); gsub(/\047\047/,"\047"); print}' file4
Path to Python Language's Binaries (this is an edge case)
```

I just noticed you said:

> Note that the quotes should remain doubled.

That's not how scripts like this are usually required to work but it's trivial to do if you really want that - if you want the doubled single quotes from the input, `Language''s`, to remain doubled instead of single, `Language's`, in the output then just remove `gsub(/\047\047/,"\047");` from the code.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk-split-records for information on `RS` and `RT`, and http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote for what `\047` means.

To save the output of any of the above in a shell variable you can do:

```
$ srctext=$(awk -v RS='\\<TEXT[(]\047(([^\047]|\047\047)+)\047[)]' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/^[^\047]+\047|\047[^\047]+$/,""); gsub(/\+\n/,""); gsub(/\047\047/,"\047"); print}' file3)
$ echo "$srctext"
This is JDubbTX's Text
```

just like you'd save the output of any other Unix command. Don't use all upper case for non-environment (exported) shell variables by the way, see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

The above was run on these input files:

```
$ head file1 file2 file3 file4
==> file1 <==
/* Create and set data area for PHP binary location - 1.0.24 */
CRTDTAARA  DTAARA(PHPPATH) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(255) +
VALUE(' ') TEXT('Path to PHP Binaries')
For that file $SRCTEXT should be "Path to PHP Binaries".

==> file2 <==
/* Create and set data area for Python binary location - 1.05 */
CRTDTAARA  DTAARA(PYPATH) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(255) +
VALUE('/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin') TEXT('Path to +
Python Binaries')

==> file3 <==
CRTDTAARA DTAARA(JWEIRICH1/MYDTA) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(30) TEXT('This is JDubbTX''s Text')

==> file4 <==
/* Create and set data area for Python binary location - 1.05 */
CRTDTAARA  DTAARA(PYPATH) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(255) +
VALUE('/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin') TEXT('Path to +
Python Language''s Binaries (this is an edge case)')
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks.  And also thanks for link about casing - I do care about such things.  Traditional IBM i languages are my bread and butter, but lately I've been getting into Bash scripting for Devops projects - and enjoying learning some new things.